# Advancing Request.InputStream before reaching ModelBinder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In our MVC 2 app we have a JSON model binder implemented like so:

```
    public virtual object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string input;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
        {
            input = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
            input,
            bindingContext.ModelType);
    }
```

After updating to MVC 4 I noticed that we were getting null incoming models for incoming JSON posts.  When digging in it became apparent that something upstream was advancing the stream.  This was easy enough to fix, like so

```
    public virtual object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string input;

        //something upstream after MVC 4 upgrade is advancing the stream to end before we can read it
        controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
        {
            input = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
            input,
            bindingContext.ModelType);
    }
```

But I am wondering what happened that made the change necessary?  Was the prior implementation only working by coincidence?

Comment: What is the value of Request.Content? Has that been populated already? If  so, that might explain why the InputStream needs to be repositioned. MVC4 also added the Restful WebAPI, which provides direct support for parsing the request body into model parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, The prior implementation was not working by coincidence.

`ASP.NET MVC 3` introduced **built-in JSON binding support** that enables action methods to receive JSON-encoded data and model-bind it to action-method parameters.

`JsonValueProviderFactory` is registered by default in `ASP.NET MVC 3` and onwards. The `JSON` value provider runs before model binding and serializes request data into a dictionary. The dictionary data is then passed to the `model binder`.

Let's see how `JsonValueProviderFactory` works.Here is link for the source code of `JsonValueProviderFactory` provided in ASP.NET MVC Open Source code [JsonValueProviderFactory.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/39d3064baf13181f5718ec5d85ba644b47d0704b/src/System.Web.Mvc/JsonValueProviderFactory.cs#L43-L62)

`GetDeserializedObject` method, defined in `JsonValueProviderFactory.cs`,  reads the `stream` if the `Content-Type` is set to `application/json` and hence it leaves the `Request.InputStream` at the end of the stream. So here `GetDeserializedObject` is called first and then `BindModel` is called. Since 
`GetDeserializedObject` has already read the stream once and advanced the `Request.InputStream` to the end of the stream, we need to reset the `Request.InputStream` again in `BindModel`

```
private static object GetDeserializedObject(ControllerContext controllerContext)
{
    if (!controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
            // not JSON request
            return null;
    }
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream);
    string bodyText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyText))
    {
        // no JSON data
        return null;
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    object jsonData = serializer.DeserializeObject(bodyText);
    return jsonData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense.  Is the dictionary you refer to the same as the Request.Content referenced in @B2K's comment?

Should I be changing my model binder implementation to work with this dictionary?